# Can't get Ad, Flurry 5.3 with ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, flurry

My app can't get `flurry` ad when build app for release in google play with `ProGuard`. If i run app without `ProGuard` everything work fine.
I enable Log and `flurry` SDK write next information:

```
02-20 16:31:09.765    8953-8953/? D/FlurryAdServingApp﹕ fetchAndDisplay: Banner
02-20 16:31:14.885    8953-8953/? D/FlurryAdServingApp﹕ Failed 20
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ClassCastException: com.flurry.sdk.it cannot be cast to com.flurry.android.impl.ads.protocol.v13.AdUnit
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.ci$4.a(Unknown Source)
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.ci$4.a(Unknown Source)
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.gg.o(Unknown Source)
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.gg.d(Unknown Source)
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.gg$1.a(Unknown Source)
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.gh.o(Unknown Source)
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.gh.a(Unknown Source)
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.gg.a(Unknown Source)
02-20 16:31:17.960    8953-9041/? W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.hk.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm not understand why his write Unknown Source if in `proguard-project.txt` i write next:

```
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Google Play Services library
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
  protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
  public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final ** CREATOR;
}
#If you are using the Google Mobile Ads SDK, add the following:
# Preserve GMS ads classes
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *;
}
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.ads.**


#If you are using the InMobi SDK, add the following:
# Preserve InMobi Ads classes
-keep class com.inmobi.** { *;
}
-dontwarn com.inmobi.**
#If you are using the Millennial Media SDK, add the following:
# Preserve Millennial Ads classes
-keep class com.millennialmedia.** { *;
}
-dontwarn com.millennialmedia.**
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same error message, "W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ClassCastException: com.flurry.sdk.it cannot be cast to com.flurry.android.impl.ads.protocol.v13.AdUnit".

I reached out to Flurry support, support@flurry.com, and 2 business days later (today), they answered saying:

> Thank you for contacting Flurry support. In your proguard config,
>   could you please change the 3rd line from:
>
> ```
> -keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> -keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
> ```
>
> Note the addition of "Signature". Please try this new configuration
>   and let us know if it works.

I made the adjustment to Proguard and the Flurry ads appear to be working now.
Summarized, my Proguard configuration for Flurry is below:

```
#Flurry
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
# Preserve Flurry mediation classes for DFP/AdMob Ads
-keep public class com.google.ads.mediation.flurry.**
```

For reference, I'm using FlurryAds-5.3.0.jar, FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar, and flurryAndroidDFPandAdMobMediationAdapter-5.0.0.r1.jar